# Opening Sqlite Db on command prompt

Tags: android

Friends,
I am working on Sqlite DB and I want to open, view or create databases through the ADB shell command.
I've written the following commands in command prompt

1. `cd C:\android-sdk_r04-windows\android-sdk-windows\tools>`
2. `adb shell`

I get a `$` after step 2. 
Any idea how I can get `sqlite>` prompt instead and perform the following task?

Suppose I want to view the databases. I've written `cd/data/data/(mypackage)/databases` sqlite3 (database)... after the `$` but it says 'Database not found.'
How can I view the databases executed through my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your target, a device or an emulator? 
In my experience, you cannot talk to a device's databases using the command prompt. You can only do so with the emulator.

Comment: Did u resolve the issue?

Comment: yes,i resolved this issue..thanks for your care

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use sqlite3 command to connect to database from adb shell. Find example of [sqlite3 form Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sqlite3.html).
This will open an sql prompt where you can execute standard commands supported. Another link which explains creating a database, creating table and viewing its contents all from command prompt (adb shell) is [here](http://vinnysoft.blogspot.com/2009/09/creating-databases-from-sqlite-shell.html).