# Android - How can I view a sql database created in my app? I'm running it on the Android emulator in Eclipse

Tags: android, sql, database, eclipse

I have an Android application that uses the Android database to create tables and store data. I'm currently running this app in the emulator in Eclipse. I have 2 questions:

1. Where can I find the actual database file (it must be on my computer somewhere right?) that is created when I run my app in the emulator?
2. Is there an easy way to view what is in my database/tables?

If I could find where the actual database file is (if there is such a thing) on my computer, then perhaps question 2 would be answered as easily as opening that file. But I really have no clue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [sqlite](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#sqlite)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hi

1. In the Eclipse look at the File Explorer tab (near the Console tab). Or look at menu "Window -> Show View -> Other... -> File Explorer". Emulator should be run. In the File Explorer window go to the folder "data/data/[your_package_name]/databases/". There you can find your database. You can export it to the your computer. At the right top corner of the window there is a button "pull a file from device". Select database, click that button and save a database on the computer.

2. Program "sqlite browser" can shows a data in the database. You can download it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/). It is easy to use.

Comment: Yes, your device must be rooted.

Comment: Quote: In the File Explorer window go to the folder "data/data/[your_package_name]/databases/" - in the app I am trying to debug, the /data folder is empty?

Answer (score 2):

The database is stored in the following location on the emulator (assuming your app has the package `com.example.app` and a database named `db-name.db`):

```
/data/data/com.example.app/db-name.db
```

You can access it from the command line as follows:

```
cmd> adb -e shell
cmd> sqlite3 /data/data/com.example.app/databases/db-name.db
sqlite> select * from table_name;
sqlite> 1|Example Item 1|1|
sqlite> 2|Example Item 2|2|
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to browse your databases inside eclipse follow these instructions taken from here:

[Android - How can I view a sql database created in my app? I'm running it on the Android emulator in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846336/android-how-can-i-view-a-sql-database-created-in-my-app-im-running-it-on-the)

1.Download the Questoid Plugin

2.Place the file in your Eclipse plugins folder (e.g. /usr/lib/eclipse/plugins)

3.Restart Eclipse

4.Start up an Android Emulator w/ Debugging in Eclipse

5.Switch to the DDMS Perspective in Eclipse

6.Go to the 'File Explorer' tab to locate your device's database file

7.Navigate to: e.g. 'data -> data -> com.myproject -> databases -> myproject

8.Open the database file in Questoid (see screen shot)

9.Switch to the 'Questoid SQLite Browser' tab that appears

10.Switch to the 'Browse Data' sub tab

11.Select your table from the drop down menu

12.Browse your data here and onward into the digital sunset

[image]