# why android cant find class Mission in dataBase

Tags: android, database, sqlite, datatable

i create an android application to show a list of mission from my data data base
this is my database manager ...but i always have error that tell me that there is no table mission in the database

```
public class DbaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private DbaseManager mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
public static final String DB_NAME = "SI.db";
public static final String DB_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/SI/DB/";
//**********************************TABLE_MISSIONS**************************************
    private static final String TABLE_MISSIONS = "Missions";
    private static final String COL_ID_MISSION = "idMission";
    private static final int NUM_COL_ID_MISSION = 0;
    private static final String COL_NOM_MISSION = "nomMission";
    private static final int NUM_COL_NOM_MISSION = 1;   
    private static final String COL_DATE_MISSION = "dateMission";
    private static final int NUM_COL_DATE_MISSION = 2;  

    private static final String CREATE_MISSIONS = 
    "CREATE TABLE "        + TABLE_MISSIONS + " ("
    + COL_ID_MISSION       + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
    + COL_NOM_MISSION      + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
    + COL_DATE_MISSION     + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
//**************************************************************** 
   public DbaseManager(Context context) {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/SI/");
            if (!folder.exists()) {folder.mkdir();}
            File dbfolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/SI/DB/");
            if (!dbfolder.exists()) {dbfolder.mkdir();}
            File photofolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/SI/Pic/");
            if (!photofolder.exists()) {photofolder.mkdir();}
            }
public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    SQLiteDatabase dbRetour = null;
    try {
        dbRetour = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_PATH+ DB_NAME, null);
        dbRetour.execSQL(CREATE_POINTS);
        dbRetour.execSQL(CREATE_MISSIONS);
        dbRetour.execSQL(CREATE_RELEVEUR);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    return dbRetour;

}
public void open(Context context) {
    mDbHelper = new DbaseManager(context);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    mDb = mDbHelper.openDataBase();

}
/**
 * Close the database
 */
@Override
public void close() {
        mDb.close();
    }
      public List<Missions> getAllMissions() {
            List<Missions> mission = new ArrayList<Missions>();

            Cursor cursor = mDb.query(DbaseManager.TABLE_MISSIONS, allMissions, null, null, null,null,null);

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                Missions missions = cursorToMissions(cursor);
                mission.add(missions);
              cursor.moveToNext();
            }
            // make sure to close the cursor
            cursor.close();
            return mission;
          }

          private Missions cursorToMissions(Cursor cursor) {
            Missions missions = new Missions(null, null);
            missions.setNomMission(cursor.getString(1));
            missions.setDateMission(cursor.getString(2));

            return missions;
          }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override   
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

this is my Missions class

```
public class Missions {
       private String nomMission;
       private String dateMission;

       public Missions(String nomMission,String dateMission)
            {
           this.nomMission=nomMission;
           this.dateMission=dateMission;
            }



    public String getNomMission() {
        return nomMission;
    }

    public void setNomMission(String nomMission) {
        this.nomMission = nomMission;
    }

    public String getDateMission() {
        return dateMission;
    }

    public void setDateMission(String dateMission) {
        this.dateMission = dateMission;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Missions [idMission="  + ", nomMission="
                + nomMission + ", dateMission=" + dateMission + "]";
    }



    }
```

and this is the activity in wich i would show my list of Missionw

```
public class MissionAct extends ListActivity {
      private DbaseManager datasource;
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addmission_activity);
        datasource = new DbaseManager(this);
        datasource.open(getBaseContext());
        List<Missions> values = datasource.getAllMissions();
        ArrayAdapter<Missions> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Missions>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
          }
}
```

and this is the Log

```
04-23 01:28:21.061: E/AndroidRuntime(12607): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 01:28:21.061: E/AndroidRuntime(12607): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tn.pfe.ybn.sigl/tn.pfe.ybn.sigl.MissionAct}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Missions: , while compiling: SELECT idMission, nomMission, dateMission FROM Missions
04-23 01:28:21.061: E/AndroidRuntime(12607): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Missions: , while compiling: SELECT idMission, nomMission, dateMission FROM Missions
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to update your manifest file to include the activity?

Comment: yes i did it  but the error is that while compiling: SELECT idMission, nomMission, dateMission FROM Missions SQLiteException: no such table: Missions

Answer (score 0):

Yes the table was not created because You need to create table inside `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)` method

Comment: i created OpenDataBase to test if the dataBase and table exist if else it create them
and in the methode open i call it==> so dont need to  reate table inside onCreate

Comment: Sorry i didn't saw that on your code before...i think you leave a space on creating a table **TABLE_MISSIONS + " ("** it will come **TABLE_MISSIONS + "("** otherwise the table name "Missions "

Comment: i change it but the same problem

Comment: Means the table was not created check it out the whether the table was created or not

Comment: you will get a answer on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846336/android-how-can-i-view-a-sql-database-created-in-my-app-im-running-it-on-the/9846595#9846595

Comment: otherwise you are using device means go to DDMS ->>> data ->>> data ->>> your package name ->>> databases

Comment: dont find the table ...i have a problem in creation but when i excute the script of my application in sqlitedataBrowser it work nicely