# Where I can Find Android database file in my app?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, sqlitestudio

I need to find the path that have the database of my application and I need to insert into my android database by SQLlitestudio.... please help

I'm using andriod Studio

thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - How can I view a sql database created in my app? I'm running it on the Android emulator in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846336/android-how-can-i-view-a-sql-database-created-in-my-app-im-running-it-on-the)

Comment: I'm using android studio ,,,, how can I access  ?

Comment: You should really learn how to google http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529766/see-database-filecontent-via-android-studio

Comment: It's in `/data/data/your.app.name/databases/your.db`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the path: /data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/databases/

P.S. May be that link can help:
http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use DbAndroid plugin for SQLiteStudio ( http://wiki.sqlitestudio.pl/index.php/DbAndroid ), although it's not free.