# Android SQLite DB datatype mismatch

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I was trying to use a SQLite database to store some to-do data in my app. And it failed when I tried to put in some data. I have searched StackOverflow, changing database or table name didn't seem to work for my case.
The error in logcat is

> statement aborts at 5: [INSERT INTO Todos(Complete,Description,Title,Deadline) VALUES (?,?,?,?)] datatype mismatch

My SQLHelper class:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "todoManager";
    // Todos table name
    private static final String TABLE_TODOS = "Todos";
    // Todos table columns names
    private static final String KEY_TITLE = "Title";
    private static final String KEY_DDL = "Deadline";
    private static final String KEY_DES = "Description";
    private static final String KEY_COM = "Complete";

    public DatabaseHelper (Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //String for creating table TODOS.
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_TODOS + " ("
                + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_DDL + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_DES + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_COM + " TEXT)";
        //Run string
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //Drop old table, if it existed.
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TODOS);
        //Create tables again.
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void delete(TodoItem item) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_TODOS, KEY_TITLE + " = " + item.getTITLE(), null);
    }

    public void addTodo(TodoItem item) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        //Prepare and save all values for insertion.
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_TITLE, item.getTITLE());
        values.put(KEY_DDL, item.getDEADLINE());
        values.put(KEY_DES, item.getDESCRIPTION());
        values.put(KEY_COM, item.getCOMPLETED());

        db.insert(TABLE_TODOS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public void updateTodo(TodoItem item) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        //Update rows
        values.put(KEY_TITLE, item.getTITLE());
        values.put(KEY_DDL, item.getDEADLINE());
        values.put(KEY_DES, item.getDESCRIPTION());
        values.put(KEY_COM, item.getCOMPLETED());

        db.update(TABLE_TODOS, values, KEY_TITLE + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(item.getTITLE())});

    }

    public ArrayList<TodoItem> getAllTodos() {
        ArrayList<TodoItem> list = new ArrayList<TodoItem>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        //Select all query
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_TODOS;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        //Add to list
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                TodoItem todo = new TodoItem(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1),
                        cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4));
                todo.setTITLE(cursor.getString(0));
                list.add(todo);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return list;
    }
```

}

My TodoItem class (I didn't put the last field in my database, is it OK?):

```
public class TodoItem {
private String TITLE = TodoListProvider.TaskEntry.COL_TITLE;
private String DESCRIPTION = TodoListProvider.TaskEntry.COL_DESCRIPTION;
private String DEADLINE = TodoListProvider.TaskEntry.COL_DEADLINE;
private String COMPLETED = TodoListProvider.TaskEntry.COL_COMPLETED;
private String TIME_CREATED = TodoListProvider.TaskEntry.COL_TIME_CREATED;

    public TodoItem(String tt, String dl,String dt,String cm,String tc) {
        this.TITLE= tt;
        this.DESCRIPTION = dt;
        this.DEADLINE = dl;
        this.COMPLETED = cm;
        this.TIME_CREATED = tc;
    }
public String getTITLE() {
    return TITLE;
}

public void setTITLE(String TITLE) {
    this.TITLE = TITLE;
}

public String getDESCRIPTION() {
    return DESCRIPTION;
}

public void setDESCRIPTION(String DETAILS) {
    this.DESCRIPTION = DETAILS;
}

public String getDEADLINE() {
    return DEADLINE;
}

public void setDEADLINE(String DEADLINE) {
    this.DEADLINE = DEADLINE;
}

public String getCOMPLETED() {
    return COMPLETED;
}

public void setCOMPLETED(String COMPLETED) {
    this.COMPLETED = COMPLETED;
}

public String getTIME_CREATED() {
    return TIME_CREATED;
}

public void setTIME_CREATED(String TIME_CREATED) {
    this.TIME_CREATED = TIME_CREATED;
}
```

}

This is how I called the database in a fragment (through a button click):

```
public class EditItemFragment extends Fragment {
private View view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_item, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    EditText title = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTitle);
    EditText deadline = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editDDL);
    EditText description = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editDescription);
    EditText complete = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editComplete);

    String Title = title.getText().toString();
    String Deadline = deadline.getText().toString();
    String Description = description.getText().toString();
    String Complete = complete.getText().toString();

    final TodoItem item = new TodoItem(Title, Deadline, Description, Complete, "now");

    Button saveBtn = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
            helper.addTodo(item);
        }
    });
```

Thanks a million if you could give me some idea about this!

Comment: Please don't use all caps for any variables that aren't constants. That's a Java code convention. Anyways you may need to uninstall the app in order to cause a schema change to work

Comment: sorry I am new. I will pay attention to it in the future :)

Comment: I think use varchar(200) instead of text in the creation of database .

Comment: hi, just as tip , first uninstall and reinstall app after changing the modifications,

Comment: @SushilKumar  do you mean like KEY_TITLE + " varchar(200), "? what's the difference?

Comment: @SushilKumar a VARCHAR in SQLite is just a limit space TEXT field. That wouldn't fix the problem

Comment: your error is "Datatype mismatch" that why i advice you .......

Comment: @SushilKumar A string variable can be stored in a TEXT field just fine, the problem likely exists elsewhere. For example, the database file or table needs recreated for any changes to take effect

Comment: @Emile have  you see your table is created Sucessfully?

Comment: @Emile define your Model instance Public

Comment: @VishalHalani how to check if my table is created successfully?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846336/android-how-can-i-view-a-sql-database-created-in-my-app-im-running-it-on-the

Comment: use this link for view of database in your studio

Comment: @Emile you have to open DDMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have exected ur code, it works fine basically that getwritable db not working in ur applications

so i have made some changes in ur code see below

**Add these codes 
DatabaseHelper.class:**

```
  private static DatabaseHelper instance;
    public static synchronized DatabaseHelper getHelper(Context context) {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        return instance;
    }


****`Add these In Ur Fragment Activity:`****


//Declare in private
    DatabaseHelper helper;
    SQLiteDatabase database;

    //In on createView:

      if (helper == null) {
        helper = DatabaseHelper.getHelper(getActivity());
        database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
```

**Permissions in manifest file:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

*Note: Whenever ur adding / modying changes in ur code at dbhelper class: please uninstall and reinstall app .*

Comment: I added these lines to the manifest file and the old problem solved! But the app crashed upon installing, said something like `Unable to start activity ComponentInfo {MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #4: Error inflating class fragment`. I may need to check this later. Anyway thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think you have wrong onCreate() method. Try to use next instead:

```
private static final String  KEY_ID = "_id";

@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //String for creating table TODOS.
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TODOS + " ("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_DDL + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_DES + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_COM + " TEXT )";
        //Run string
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }
```

KEY_ID - is required parameter.

Comment: Integer Primary Key is always required? OMG I didn't know that.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to recreate the scheme automatically, increase the DATABASE_VERSION

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
```

If you don't you have to uninstall the app to recreate the scheme.